# What is the grammar of "the blur the protect the identity"

Tags: nouns

When I make an unnecessary blur to hide the identity of the users in the Meta, [one user makes fun of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268408/why-do-my-accounts-rank-appear-in-the-top-of-the-second-page-of-the-list-while#comment870065_268408):

> I like **the blur the protect the identity** of users we can easily find ourselves...

I have no idea what grammar does this sentence base on. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's a typo. Needed to be "I like the blur ***to*** protect the identity..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just about a trivial typo in an online comment

Comment: @FumbleFingers [which flag should I use?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2716/11458)

Comment: @Oooker: It doesn't really matter. Regardless of your rep-based privileges, I don't think you can permanently *delete* the question, since an answer has actually been posted. But I've no doubt three more users will endorse my closevote (one already has), so it'll get closed soon enough. And of course, no *blame* attaches to you for having asked an Off Topic question, since you could hardly be expected to realise it was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made two mistakes.

I should have written *I like the blur to protect the identity of users we can easily find ourselves...*

And I shouldn't try to make fun of users. Duly noted and please accept my apologies.

Comment: what's the problem? I don't see any offense. And why do you even delete your second comment, which is actually fun and only make fun to yourself?

Comment: It all got lost in translation I guess...

Comment: what do you mean by translation?

Comment: The translation between what is in my mind, the intent, searching for English words to go with it and the actual muscle impulses to hit the correct keys on the keyboard.